# Training of SVM classifier in OpenCV using SIFT and ORB features

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, svm, sift

I'm trying to train a SVM classifier to recognize pedestrians in a set of 64x128 images. I've already done that using HOG features, and now I need to implement the same thing using SIFT and ORB. For HOG features, I had always the same number of features (3780), so that the matrix for the train was image_number by 3780. Now, using SIFT extractor I get keypoints of different sizes. How can I create a matrix for the classifier using these keypoints of different sizes?

Many thanks for your help!

I solved the descriptors' issue putting all of them in the same row. However, I found out that most of desriptors have a 0 value, so the classifier doesn't work well. Do you know how can I solve this problem?

This is a piece of the code:

```
DenseFeatureDetector detector;
SiftDescriptorExtractor descriptor;
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;


//for every image I compute te SIFT
detector.detect(image, keypoints);
Mat desc;
descriptor.compute(image,keypoints, desc);
Mat v(1,30976,CV_32FC1);
    for (int j = 0; j<desc.rows; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k<desc.cols; k++){
            v.at<float>(0,128*j+k) = desc.at<float>(j,k);

        }
    } //now in vector v there are all the descriptors (the problem is that most of them have 0 value)

descriptormat.push_back(v);  //descriptormat is the cv::Mat that I use to train the SVM
```

Answer (score 5):

Usually, people vector-quantize SIFT or ORB features and build histograms (bags-of-words model). This would give you a fixed size vector for every training and testing image.

Comment: +1 for vector quantization( or just simple k-means k clusters from n SIFT vector features).

Comment: Thanks, but can you please explain what exactly is this quantization? Do I have an average of the N (128x1) vectors, where N is the number of keypoints ?

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw See section 2.3 of [Visual Categorization with Bags of Keypoints](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/AP06/Papers/csurka-eccv-04.pdf), or Figure 1 from [Visual Word Ambiguity](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~jvgemert/pub/GemertTPAMI09Ambiguity.pdf). The quantization generally splits up the 128-D space into K regions, each defined by a cluster center. Features are quantized based on which cluster center they are closest to.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a big matrix and push_back the descriptors computed for each image. Example (not checked)

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    cv::SIFT sift;
    cv::Mat dataMatrix(0, 128, CV_32F); // 0 rows, 128 cols is SIFT dimension, I think there is a method that gives you the descriptor dimension exactly. type is 32F if I remember well, must check
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
      cv::Mat img = cv::imread(argv[i]);
      std::vector<cv::KeyPoints> kp;
      cv::Mat desc;
      sift(img, cv::noArray(), keypoints, desc);
      dataMatrix.push_back(desc);
    }

    // Now train SVM with dataMatrix
    assert(dataMatrix.rows > 0);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I followed your suggestion and as for the sift extraction it works well, but when I train and test the svm I get this error: "OpenCV Eror: inccorrect size of input array<input sample must be 1-dimensional vector> in cvPreparePredictData". I don't know how I solve that, because for HOG I had a single descriptor for each image, but now for each image I have a matrix of as many descriptors as number of keypoints: how can I train and test the svm in this situation?