# Opencv: Train SVM with FAST keypoints and BRIEF features

Tags: python, opencv, svm

I want to train a SVM for object detection. At this point I have a python script which detects FAST keypoints and extracts BRIEF features at that location.

Now I don't know how to use these descriptors to train a SVM.

Would you tell me please:

1. How to use the descriptors to train the SVM (As far as I know these descriptors should be my train data)?
2. What are labels used for and how I can get them?

Comment: maybe you can adapt the answer for sift features: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048891/training-of-svm-classifier-using-sift-features maybe seach for svm in combination with sift or surf in general. They seem to normally use bag of words methods.

Comment: Sift and surf are non-free algorithms and I don't want to use them. The other descriptors are binary and I can't use them with bag of words.

Comment: can't binary descriptors be used the same way as floating point descriptors? e.g. you have n bins (SIFT/SURF: 64 or 128 floating point values, BINARY: x bits) and the more similar the bins, the more similar the features. Didnt use binary descriptors yet, but I thought the description idea was analogue to traditional descriptors?! So I thought you could use both: binary descriptor with general bag-of-words and if there are methods to use svm with sift/surf you could use them with binary descriptors too.

Comment: no, unfortunately you cannot use binary descriptors successfully with either an svm, nor bag-of-words. both techniques rely heavily on L2 distance, and thus *need* float descriptors. (and no, just converting them is not a valid option)

Comment: wait... bag-of-words means to use a number of representatives for each object category and decide from an new input to which of those category groups the "distance" (e.g. measured from a representative or the minimum distance from all representatives over all groups) is the best, doesn't it? Here binary bag of words is shown for ORB: http://imagelab.ing.unimore.it/imagelab/pubblicazioni/2013ElectronicImaging.pdf

Comment: `Representing Local Binary Descriptors with
BossaNova for Visual Recognition` by `Carlos Caetanoy, Sandra Avila, et al.` is another paper addressing binary bag-of-words. In a short view it looks they cite other binary bag-of-words methods, too, so maybe worth to read it.

Comment: yes, true. i meant opencv's implementation, which is using kmeans-clustering.

Comment: Well maybe I should give up this method or choose SURF. 

I'd like to ask, what do you think about HOG?

Comment: @berak You have commented my questions before and you saw how I struggle with my problem. I'm trying to implement my project to graduate. I really need your help. 

Since I can't use BRIEF, what approach should I use to create an object detector? The project is an Android application. (Haar classifier is not a variant because I tried it and it is really hard to train and I have no time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To train a SVM you would need a matrix `X` with your features and a vector `y` with your labels. It should look like this for 3 images and two features:

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> X = [[0, 0],   <- negative 0
         [1, 3],   <- positive 1
          2, 5]]   <- negative 0
>>> y = [0,   
         1,
         0]
>>> model = svm.SVC()
>>> model.fit(X, y)
```

The training set would consist of several images, each image would be a row of `X` and `y`.

### Labels:

For the labels `y` you need positive and negative examples (0 or 1):

> **Positive Samples**
>
> You can specify positive samples in two ways. One way is to specify
>   rectangular regions in a larger image. The regions contain the objects
>   of interest. The other approach is to crop out the object of interest
>   from the image and save it as a separate image. Then, you can specify
>   the region to be the entire image. You can also generate more positive
>   samples from existing ones by adding rotation or noise, or by varying
>   brightness or contrast.
>
> **Negative Samples**
>
> Images that do not contain objects of interest.
>
> [*slightly edited from [here]](http://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html)*

### Feature matrix X:

Here you can get creative but I will mention a simple idea. Make `height * width` features, one for each pixel of each image, but make them all 0 except in a small region around the FAST keypoints. In the end your `X` matrix will have dimension (`n_images`, `height*width`).

Another commonly used idea is Bag of Words. The `X` matrix must have a fixed number of features/columns and the number of keypoints is variable. This is a representation problem but it can be solved binning them in a histogram with a fixed number of bins. For details see for example [this paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/AP06/Papers/csurka-eccv-04.pdf).

You will have to consult the specialized literature to come up with more ways to incorporate the BRIEF features but I hope this will give you an idea on how to get started.

Comment: he could use width times height  times BRIEF-descriptor-dimension but not sure about overfitting in SVM.

Comment: I can't understand when I have the features extracted, why should I "Make height * width features, one for each pixel of each image".

Also I can't use BOW with binary descriptor.

Comment: You have to represent your image numerically somehow and converting one image to a long `height*width` vector is the simplest of all approaches. With a mask on your keypoints you can improve the naive  representation.