# Train svm with ORB descriptors?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, orb

Hi i've been trying to train a svm with features, but i don't understand what to do with the descriptors that are computed of the keypoints using ORB. I know that svm needs a data matrix and a label matrix, but i don't know how can i pass the descriptors Mat to a valid format.
I've read about the BoF (Bag of Words/Features) but i don't know how to use it. 
Thanks for any help.

The code below allows me to get the descriptors of an image. What's the next step?

```
            std::vector<KeyPoint> kp;
            Mat desc;
        // Default parameters of ORB
            int nfeatures = 128; 
            float scaleFactor = 1.2f; 
            int nlevels = 8;    
            int edgeThreshold = 15; // Changed default (31);
            int firstLevel = 0; 
            int WTA_K = 2; 
            int scoreType = ORB::HARRIS_SCORE; 
            int patchSize = 31; 
            int fastThreshold = 20;

            Ptr<ORB> myORB = ORB::create(nfeatures, scaleFactor, nlevels, edgeThreshold, firstLevel, WTA_K, scoreType,
                patchSize, fastThreshold);

            myORB->detectAndCompute(src, Mat(), kp, desc);

            features.push_back(desc);
```

Comment: did you read this (answer and comments)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706012/opencv-train-svm-with-fast-keypoints-and-brief-features

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to use python with OpenCV that will save you a lot of time. In python, this will be just 10 lines of code.

You can refer to this [link](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_orb/py_orb.html) for ORB. And once you get features then you can use [scikit-learn svm](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) for training an SVM classifier.