# Use a SVM with Key Points

Tags: image-processing, svm, descriptor

So I have the same Problem as discused in this post.

[Training of SVM classifier using SIFT features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048891/training-of-svm-classifier-using-sift-features)

I read a lot of tutorials and posts about this, but I have some comprehension questions about the bag of words model, how to put my descriptors in it and how to train the SVM with it.

On the previous step of my current project I used HOG+SVM and there every image was one row if my trainingmatrix. Before I extract my HOG descriptor I rezised the image to the size of the descriptor, so all my rows had the same length.

Now I wanted to use binary descriptors. If I detect for example 36 Key Points in my image and discribe them, I get a a 36x250 matrix. And for a other image a 29x250 matrix. Now I think I have to use the Bag of Words method from OpenCV to build a dictionary for my SVM.

So I extract the descriptors from the Key Points and add them to my BOW, after that I cluster it into a vocabulary and now I´m out.
I read a lot of tutorials and posts, but I dont get this step.

Could someone explain whats happening after that? 
How is my data stored? 
How does the BOWImgDescriptorExtractor work?
Do I put negative and positive samples to the BOW?

I am sorry if this was asked a hundred times already, but I am not a professional programmer and I often have problems if everything is clustered in a few functions and everyone says its simple.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier than I think you're imagining. For ease of reading I'll write it out in steps for you.

1. take all examples from your training set and apply HOG to get the features- you completely forget about what the class is just make sure you have examples from each class.
2. Then you take all these features you extracted and create a bag of words using a clustering algorithms - so instead of like 1000 features you'd have 25 "visual words".
3. Now when you train the algorithm you again extract HOG features from each image, but you find which "word" its closest to using a distance function - generally L1 or L2. Now each image instead of being represented by hog features its being represented by word that you generally number 1-n.
4. Feed in your data to your svm to train :)
5. When you go to test you again extract HOG, transform into BOW, and feed this new representation and model into your test function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Now the most stuff became clear and I understand what´s going on in the tutorials. Thank you very much.