# Preparing SIFT descriptors for further SVM classification (OpenCV 3, sklearn)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I'm trying to classify images using SIFT-computed local descriptors with Bag of Visual Words, KMeans clustering and histograms.

I've read a lot of SO answers and tried to follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27524661/4674270), however, it feels like I don't understand how the whole pipeline should work. Below will be the code I've implemented and it works reeeally slow.

That's why I'm asking this question: to clarify my understanding of using SIFT descriptors for classification and verify my code implementation.

I hope to get feedback on my understanding and get some help in improving my knowledge of the concept.

---

Firstly, I've written a class wrapper for SIFT. My wrapper computes SIFT descriptors on image patches using sliding window. It also uses Root SIFT for descriptors computation. The function `detectAndCompute` is its main function and basically it takes an image as an argument, crops it into several sub-images using sliding window, computes Root SIFT descriptors for each sub-image and unites all the descriptors from all sub-images into a single matrix of descriptors.

```
class DenseRootSIFT(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

    def detectAndCompute(self, image, step_size=12, window_size=(10, 10)):
        if window_size is None:
            winH, winW = image.shape[:2]
            window_size = (winW // 4, winH // 4)

        descriptors = np.array([], dtype=np.float32).reshape(0, 128)
        for crop in self._crop_image(image, step_size, window_size):
            crop = cv2.cvtColor(crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            descs = self._detectAndCompute(crop)[1]
            if descs is not None:
                descriptors = np.vstack([descriptors, self._detectAndCompute(crop)[1]])
        return descriptors

    def _detect(self, image):
        return self.sift.detect(image)

    def _compute(self, image, kps, eps=1e-7):
        kps, descs = self.sift.compute(image, kps)

        if len(kps) == 0:
            return [], None

        descs /= (descs.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True) + eps)
        descs = np.sqrt(descs)
        return kps, descs

    def _detectAndCompute(self, image):
        kps = self._detect(image)
        return self._compute(image, kps)

    def _sliding_window(self, image, step_size, window_size):
        for y in xrange(0, image.shape[0], step_size):
            for x in xrange(0, image.shape[1], step_size):
                yield (x, y, image[y:y + window_size[1], x:x + window_size[0]])

    def _crop_image(self, image, step_size=12, window_size=(10, 10)):
        crops = []
        winH, winW = window_size
        for (x, y, window) in self._sliding_window(image, step_size=step_size, window_size=(winW, winH)):
            if window.shape[0] != winH or window.shape[1] != winW:
                continue
            crops.append(image[y:y+winH, x:x+winW])
        return np.array(crops)
```

Below I post my class called `DenseRootSiftPreparator` that should provide tools for extracting SIFT features from image and preparing them for further classification (particularly, with LinearSVC from sklearn).

So, I follow this process:

1. Generate a codebook (`_generate_codebook` function in the class below). The codebook is generated by applying mini-batch KMeans clustering with 2048 clusters. As an output, the function returns a `2048 x 128` matrix.
2. Then I'm trying to create a histogram for each image in the dataset by following the [instructions I've posted above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27524661/4674270). A histogram for a single image is created using `_create_histogram` function. At first, the histogram is initialized with zeros. Then the descriptors get computed for the input image and for each descriptor, I'm trying to find the index of the closest descriptor in the previously generated codebook (using [KDTree from scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html)) and increment the value of the histogram on that index. Then I L2-normalize the histogram array and return it. The same process is repeated for each image. And it is very very slow.

Here's the code for `DenseRootSiftPreparator`:

```
class DenseRootSiftPreparator(object):
    def __init__(self, histogram_size=2048):
        self.X = []
        self.dense_root_sift = DenseRootSIFT()
        self.histogram_size = histogram_size

    def fit(self, image_dataset, y=None):
        # @param image_dataset - array of images in OpenCV format
        self.X = image_dataset

    def extract_descriptors_and_prepare_for_classification(self, image):
        return self._get_histograms_for_image(image)

    def _get_histograms_for_image(self, image):
        codebook = self._generate_codebook(image)
        histograms = []

        for img in self.X:
            histogram = self._create_histogram(img, self.histogram_size, codebook)
            histograms.append(histogram)
        return histograms

    def _create_histogram(self, image, hist_size, codebook):
        histogram = np.zeros(hist_size)
        descriptors = self.dense_root_sift.detectAndCompute(image, window_size=None)
        tree = spatial.KDTree(codebook)

        for i in xrange(len(descriptors)):
            histogram[tree.query(descriptors[i])[1]] += 1

        return normalize(histogram[:, np.newaxis], axis=0).ravel()

    def _generate_codebook(self, image):
        descriptors = self.dense_root_sift.detectAndCompute(image, window_size=None)
        kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=2048, batch_size=128,
                                n_init=10, max_no_improvement=10)
        kmeans.fit(descriptors)
        codebook = kmeans.cluster_centers_[:]
        return codebook
```

I would test my code in the following way:

```
images = get_images_dataset()
test_input_img = cv2.imread('test_input_image.jpg')
histogram_extractor = DenseRootSiftPreparator()
histogram_extractor.fit(images)
hists = histogram_extractor.extract_descriptors_and_prepare_for_classification(test_input_img)
```

Here're my imports (just in case):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial
import cv2
from cv2.xfeatures2d import SIFT_create
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
```

---

My main questions:

- Is my understanding of creating the Bag of Visual Words model using
  SIFT descriptors correct?
- If not, what am I doing wrong? What could be done better?
- Are the functions I've described above work as they should work or I'm missing something out?
- Is there a way of making the SIFT descriptor preparation for classification process better and more effecient?